Update Description, Data Owner and Field Usage values on Custom and Standard fields
We wanted to update the fields Description, Data Owner, Field Usage on Custom and Standard Fields if possible in batch.

We found out that those Fields are part of the FieldDefinition Object accessible via the Tooling API.
In the following query BusinessOwnerId is the 'Data Owner' and BusinessStatus is the 'Field Usage' (link to Documentation).
SELECT Id,Description,BusinessOwnerId,BusinessStatus FROM FieldDefinition WHERE EntityDefinitionId = 'Lead'

According to the documentation only GET requests are allowed on FieldDefinition.
Is there a way to update those fields (they are updatable via the UI for Custom Fields but not for Standard ones)?

There seems to be a solution which works only on Custom Fields.
Using a package.xml.
Write a package.xml (using the Package.xml Generator plugin on vscode for ex.)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Lead.Custom_Field1__c</members>
        <members>Lead.Custom_Field2__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <version>60.0</version>
</Package>

Retrieve the metadata related to the target custom Fields using SFDX or vscode. The metadata will look like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomField xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>Custom_Field1__c</fullName>
    <businessOwnerGroup>DataOwner_xxxxxx</businessOwnerGroup>
    <businessStatus>DeprecateCandidate</businessStatus>
    <description>This is the custom Field Description.</description>
    ...other tags
</CustomField>

Write an automation which sets the needed attributes and push them back to Salesforce
